# Logback not writing to file

Tags: linux, maven, javafx, netbeans

I am attempting to add logging to my application and I am running into this problem. I have reviewed past questions and no solution has been found yet.

I get all the console messages but nothing to the specified file

logback.xml configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration debug="true">
  <property name="LOG_DIR" value="${application.home}}/src/main/resources/Logging" />
    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
      <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
        <Pattern>%d{"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"} %-5level %file:%line - %msg%n</Pattern>
      </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>"${LOG_DIR}/jLoggerFX.log"</file>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
      <Pattern>%d{"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"} %-5level %file:%line - %msg%n</Pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <root level="TRACE"> <appender-ref ref="FILE" /> </root>
  <root level="INFO"> <appender-ref ref="FILE" /> </root>
  <root level="DEBUG"> <appender-ref ref="FILE" /> </root>
  <root level="WARN"> <appender-ref ref="FILE" /> </root>
  <root level="ERROR"> <appender-ref ref="FILE" /> </root>

  <logger name="default" level="INFO" additivity="true">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE"/> 
  </logger>
  <logger name="mainlogger" level="INFO" additivity="true">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE"/> 
  </logger>
  <logger name="maplogger"  level="INFO" additivity="true">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE"/> 
  </logger>
```

In the MainController.java code:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
. . .
private Logger mainlogger;
. . .
mainlogger = ((Logger)  LoggerFactory.getLogger(MainController.class));
...
String msg;
msg  = "MainController::initialize 296: err=";
msg += e.getMessage();
mainlogger.info(msg);
```

I do get the formatted messages on the console correctly, but it does not write to the file. Among other things, I have tried it without the property elements, tried to hard code the pathname, and not specify a pathname. I have yet to be able to write anything to a file.

Enviroment:
JAVAFX SDK 17 (Zulu)
Project: NetBeans 19 MAVEN
OS: Linux Mint LMDE 6

**UPDATE:**
I have simplified the configuration file as below. It exists in the project root along with the pom.xml and .ini file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <variable>
    name="FILE_NAME 
    value="/home/ken/bin/logs/jLoggerFX.log"
  </variable>
  <appender 
    name="STDOUT" 
    class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <!-- encoders are assigned the type ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder by default -->
    <encoder>
      <pattern>
        %level %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %logger{36} -%kvp- %msg%n
      </pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <appender 
    name="FILEOUT" 
    class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>${FILE_NAME}</file>
    <encoder>
      <pattern>
        %level %d{"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"} %file:%line -%kvp- %msg%n
      </pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <logger 
    name="com" 
    level="ALL" 
    additivity="true">
    <appender-ref ref="FILEOUT"/>
  </logger>
  <logger 
     name="com.ad5xj" 
     level="ALL" 
     additivity="true">
     <appender-ref ref="FILEOUT"/>
   </logger>
    <logger 
      name="com.ad5xj.JLoggerFX"
      level="ALL" 
      additivity="true">
      <appender-ref ref="FILEOUT"/>
     </logger>
     <logger 
       name="com.ad5xj.GUI.MapViewController"
       level="ALL" 
       additivity="true">
       <appender-ref ref="FILEOUT"/>
     </logger>

     <root level="DEBUG"> 
       <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" /> 
     </root>
</configuration>
```

If I have cleared all the other objections, it almost seems that the location is wrong. I know the Logback docs make a point about it being in the class path. As far as I can tell everything else located in the same place is found (class path). Not sure where to go from here.

Comment: The `name` of a logger is not the variable name it's assigned to. See [`getLogger(Class)`](https://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/LoggerFactory.html#getLogger-java.lang.Class-) for more details. Also, `src/main/resources` will not exist after deployment, not to mention that log files are not a _resource_. I'm also surprised you are seeing anything in the console; as far as I can tell, you never register the `CONSOLE` appender with any logger.

Comment: I also recommend using lazy methods like [`info(String,Object)`](https://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/Logger.html#info-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-) instead of building the message eagerly and calling `info(String)`. And note `LoggerFactory.getLogger` already returns a `Logger`, there's no need for the cast.

Comment: The Logger instance can be made static as it is based on the class.

Comment: Thank you so much for all the comments.

So far, I am still unable to get logback to write to a file. I have changed the location to my $home folder in a named location (/home/user/bin/JLoggerFX but still no soap. 

Not sure what the advantage is to the lazy method mentioned. Besides it did not change the result nor did making the logger static.

Comment: UPDATE: I have added some debug code to the application to try to narrow the possibilities. I added the following:

            // assume SLF4J is bound to logback in the current environment
            lc = (LoggerContext)LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
            // print logback's internal status
            String folder = lc.getProperty("LOG_PATH");
            String file = lc.getProperty("FILE_NAME");
            System.out.println("folder="+folder + "/" + "file="+file);

The result printed folder=null/file=null

Still trying to find out why.

Comment: "_Not sure what the advantage is to the lazy method mentioned. Besides it did not change the result nor did making the logger static_" – The advantage is that it's lazy (i.e., the message won't be computed if the info level is not enabled, a filter stops the message from being printed, etc.). And making the logger static is just convention (it also means the logger is only looked up once instead of every time an instance is created). That said, those two recommendations are only to help with using a logging framework in Java, they are not meant to solve your problem.

Comment: The biggest problem I can see in your question is using the wrong value for `name` in the configuration file. You're getting the logger via `LoggerFactory#getLogger(Class)`. That means the name of the logger is the fully qualified name of the class. So, if the class is `Foo` in package `com.example`, then the name is `"com.example.Foo"`. With "additivity" enabled for each, you could configure the root logger, the `"com"` logger, the `"com.example"` logger, or the `"com.example.Foo"` logger. But you're configuring e.g., the `"mainLogger"`, which is not in the hierarchy.

Comment: Additionally, according to [Logback's documentation](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#automaticConf), if the configuration files are not found, then it will fall back to a basic configuration that "_consists of a ConsoleAppender attached to the root logger. The output is formatted using a PatternLayoutEncoder set to the pattern `%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} -%kvp- %msg%n`_". As I mentioned earlier, I'm surprised you're seeing console output at all, since you don't add the `CONSOLE` appender to any logger. Are you sure your configuration is being loaded?

Comment: And I see you have a `<root/>` element for each level? I'm surprised that doesn't cause an error (assuming your configuration is being loaded in the first place). If that _does not_ cause an error, I wouldn't be surprised if only the last one takes effect (at least regarding the level), meaning your "info"-level log won't be logged, because the level is set to "error".

Comment: OK, I can answer a couple of these questions.

Yes, I am loading the configuration. It follows the formatting and file paths so I know it is being loaded.

At this point, all I am getting is console output. I will revise may configuration and see what happens there.

Comment: I rolled back your last edit because the answer doesn't belong in the question. On this site, [we maintain a strict separation between questions and answers](/tour). If you've found the solution to your own problem, that's great! Please [answer your own question](/help/self-answer) in the space for an answer below.